# Stop preview-latex from overwriting file

Tags: auctex, preview

Is there a way to prevent preview-latex (on emacs through AucTex) from overwriting the main pdf when I preview the whole document with C-c C-p C-d?

Edit:

So, for example, if I use C-c C-p C-d, the following is displayed in emacs: [image: LaTeX preview]
but my document turns to:
[image: Output pdf]

What I'm wondering is if there is a way for some "scratch" pdf to be used for what is shown in the second screenshot, rather than the main pdf usually used for the output

Comment: Really there are not previews in Latex. What you see is not a preview, is just a post-view of the  pdf.  Other editors (e.g.,lyx, gummi) make the illusion of true  pre-view making that pdf in a temporal directory, but the pdf of the working directory is just a copy of a final pdf as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired effect using `preview-buffer` (`C-c C-p C-b`).